# Video Processing issue in Android

Tags: android

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quvideo.xiaoying`

I have to go through this app and found that this app is using a .xyt file to create video preview and video effects. Can anyone have an idea how to create a .xyt file from video and access .xytfile to android  it contains data like this

```
 <root>
    <version value="0x30000"/>
    <preprocess value="1"/>
    <color_space in="0x4000" out="0x4000"/>
    <cache_cfg count="2">
        <item origin_type="0x1000" cache_count="1" is_output="0" color_space="0x4000"/>
        <item origin_type="0x2000" cache_count="1" is_output="1" color_space="0x4000"/>
    </cache_cfg>
    <property count="0"/>
    <effect_list count="4">
        <effect type="2" param="3000" start="0" length="-1" is_static="0" is_by_pass="1" viewport_alignment="0x60"/>
        <effect type="2" param="3001" start="0" length="-1" is_static="0" single_time="5000" interval_time="5000" is_by_pass="0" viewport_alignment="0xa"/>
        <effect type="2" param="3002" start="5000" length="-1" is_static="0" single_time="5000" interval_time="5000" is_by_pass="0" viewport_alignment="0xa"/>
        <effect type="2" param="3003" start="0" length="-1" is_static="0" is_by_pass="0" viewport_alignment="0x60"/>
    </effect_list>
</root>ï»¿<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for security issue they use kind of unknown extension for file, and change the extension to original while using it.

Like it is possible that they are using **.xyt** extension and convert it to **.mp4** while processing with video.

`Try to convert it to another video file extension any play it.`